# Finding A Vector with a specific angle

Tags: linear-algebra

How do you find the vector of length 2 in ℝ2 making an angle of 30∘ with the x-axis?

Comment: Please search before asking.

Answer (score 1):

say (x,y) is the vector you are looking for.
it have to fulfill both:

1. sqrt(x^2 + y^2) = 2
2. tan(30) = y/x

then just solve the system

Comment: I'm not sure how to, can you please add a more detailed example.

Comment: as @Famous Blue Raincoat said, see: http://math.stackexchange.com/a/149435/156457
Ask if it still not clear

Answer (score 1):

$|v| = 2 \Rightarrow v = 2(\cos t, \sin t)$

$i = (1,0)$

$v \cdot (± i) = |v| \cdot |±i| \cdot \cos 30°$

$2(\cos t, \sin t) \cdot (±1, 0) = 2 \cdot 1 \cdot \frac{\sqrt{3}}{2}$

$± \cos t + 0 = \frac{\sqrt{3}}{2}$

$\cos t = ± \frac{\sqrt{3}}{2}$

$\cos^2t + \sin^2t = 1$

$\sin t = ± 1 / 2$

There are four vectors. [++], [+-], [-+], [--]